# Mod rewrite and redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have sub page on my website:

example.com/first-page.php

i want redirect it and using mod rewrite to change extension to html example:

example.com/first-page.html

how do this??  I was write this code:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^electronic\.html  /genre5\.php
RewriteRule ^genre5.php$ http://example.com/electronic.php [L,R=301]
```

I get this message: 
http://prntscr.com/a5vwj3

I want rewrite to html and when i will go to genre5.php page i will automaticly reditect to electronic.html how make this?

Comment: when i leave only first line:
RewriteRule ^electronic.html /genre5.php RewriteRule ^genre5.php$

i have problpem because if i will go into page genre.php or electronic.html i have the same page

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^genre5.php$ http://example.com/electronic.html [R=301]
```

Right now it may be a loop of redirects indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I was found solution:

```
RewriteRule ^muzyka-pop\.html  /genre3\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/genre3.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^muzyka-pop\.html  /genre3\.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

It rewrite genre3.php to muzyka-pop.html and when you go to genre3.php page you will be also redirect to muzyka-pop.html :)

Problem with duplicate content was solved.